# Why is my TearDown method throwing the following System.TypeLoadException?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, coded-ui-tests, microsoft-test-manager

**The Set Up**

I have TFS 2012, VS 2013 and Test Controller 2013 on my machine which runs Windows 8.1 x64

I have installed a Windows 7 x86 VM and on it I've installed VS 2012, VS 2013 and Test Controller 2012 (in that order). The VM is my test controller.

**The Issue**

I'm attempting to test a very simple scenario where I have a Coded UI test (manually programmed; I didn't use the record and playback feature) where Internet Explorer is launched with google.com and I search for the term *calculator*

This works just fine on my machine. When I try to run the test via Test Manager, however,  I get the following error:

> TestCleanup method CalculatorTest.TestCases.CalculateTest.TearDown threw exception. System.TypeLoadException: System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.ApplicationBase' from assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'..

The browser launches with google.com but it closes soon after without performing the search and the above error message is shown in Test Manager.

Could anyone please help me by shedding some light on the reason behind this?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a Visual studio versioning issue and I am guessing that since you have both VS2012 and 2013 installed, the incorrect version of the assembly is being loaded. I would have a look at the reference of the assembly that it fails to load and check that in the references, the specificversion property is set to false. If this doesn't work, try removing and re-adding the reference (e.g. the 2012 framework version) if that is what you are running under.

Comment: I tried setting the specific version property to false but sadly it didn't help.

I also tried copying the DLL for Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting into a folder which is part of the solution and added the copied DLL as the reference for the said library. I thought this would avoid any such version conflicts but unfortunately I still got this issue.

Comment: What version of the .net framework are you targeting, 4 or 4.5. and do you want to use vs 2012 or 2013? e.g. if you want to use 2012 instead of 2013, sometimes in the project location, you can delete the .suo file, then right-click and open with 2012. Also worth trying the copy local property of the reference as mentioned below, which would force it to use the specific version of the framework version of the assembly you are targeting.

Comment: I set 4.5 as the target framework and I intend to use VS 2013. It's only TFS and Test Controller that is 2012. Also I'm using Microsoft Test Manager 2013

Comment: One other thing to check - it may be worth trying the following: in Solution Explorer, right-click solution then configuration. Try changing the "Active solution platform" to either x86 or x64 and then try a rebuild then another run.

Answer (score 0):

try setting copy local to 'true' for the reference and then create a build to test using MTM.